# Am I correctly connecting the storyboard elements to the Expanding Collection library?

Tags: ios, swift

Hello all I'm trying to use [Expanding Collection](https://github.com/Ramotion/expanding-collection) library for the development of my app, but I'm having a hard time following the instructions on how to set it up.

I have installed the library via Pod, but I'm confused on how to link up the .xib file with the `BasePageCollectionCell`.

This is what I have so far:

The first step is to create a `CollectionViewCell` that inherits from `BasePageCollectionCell` the code is shown below:

```
class DeckCollectionViewCell: BasePageCollectionCell {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

}
```

There is also a `DeckCollectionViewCell.xib` file that is associated for this class which shown below:

[image]

I have set up all the constraints that were in the instructions but I have have actually linked the `UIViews` and `NSLayoutConstraint` of my `.xib` file to the class that is in folder that contains the code for the library of `Expanding Collection` (shown below). Which I don't think is correct, regardless I have continued onwards to the next step.

[image]

The second step is to create a `CollectionViewController` that inherits from `ExpandingViewController` which I was able to do. The code is shown below:

```
class ExpandingDeckViewController: ExpandingViewController {

    var items = [1,2,3,4,5]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        itemSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: 150)
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // register cell
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "DeckCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil)
        collectionView?.registerNib(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "deckCell")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}

extension ExpandingDeckViewController {


    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("deckCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        // configure cell
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! DeckCollectionViewCell
        if cell.isOpened == true {
            let tvc: ExpandingTableViewController = ExpandingDeckTableViewController(style: .Plain)
            pushToViewController(tvc)
        }
        cell.cellIsOpen(!cell.isOpened)
    }
}
```

The last step is to create the transition animations in which the first step is to subclass the `ExpandingTableViewController which I have done but I won't show the code as it is just boilerplate code.

Although I problem comes in step 3 of the transition animation instructions:

> 3) Call the push method in YourViewController to YourTableViewController

I have implemented this via:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! DeckCollectionViewCell
    if cell.isOpened == true {
        let tvc: ExpandingTableViewController = ExpandingDeckTableViewController(style: .Plain)
        pushToViewController(tvc)
    }
    cell.cellIsOpen(!cell.isOpened)
}
```

So everything complies and runs, but the question that I have is that since I have connected the `.xib` directly to Expanding Collection's code, wouldn't it make it un-reusable? I don't know if I'm connecting the storyboard elements to the code correctly!

Comment: You would typically want to show what you have tried so far to get a real answer on SO and avoid downvotes.  It might also help to use the correct name ("ExpandingCollection" or "Expanding Collection" rather than "Expanding Collection**s**") to get better results in a search

Comment: Thank you for your comment I have updated my question!